# Using Offset in Custom Post Type Query

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, offsets

I'm using the following query for a custom post type:

```
<?php
             $posts = get_posts(array(
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'offset' => 20,
                'post_type' => 'faqs'

             ));


            if($posts)
            {

                foreach($posts as $post)
                {
                    echo '<li class="faq">
                        <p class="title"><a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . get_the_title($post->ID) . '</a></p></li>';
                        /*<h4 class="title"><a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . get_the_title($post->ID) . '</a></h4><p>' . get_the_excerpt($post->ID) . '</p></li>'; */
                }

            }
             wp_reset_query();
            ?>
```

Is there a reason as to why the offset parameter doesn't work? Perhaps I need to write an entirely different query altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Reason of this behavior is pretty simple. First of all you have to know that `get_posts` uses `WP_Query` to get posts.

So let's look at WP_Query implementation. On [line 1998 of query.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/query.php#L1998) you can find:

```
if ( $q['posts_per_page'] == -1 ) {
    $q['nopaging'] = true;
```

Then on [line 2544 of query.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/query.php#L2544) you find:

```
if ( empty($q['nopaging']) && !$this->is_singular ) {
    $page = absint($q['paged']);
    if ( !$page )
        $page = 1;

    if ( empty($q['offset']) ) {
        $pgstrt = ($page - 1) * $q['posts_per_page'] . ', ';
    } else { // we're ignoring $page and using 'offset'
        $q['offset'] = absint($q['offset']);
        $pgstrt = $q['offset'] . ', ';
    }
    $limits = 'LIMIT ' . $pgstrt . $q['posts_per_page'];
}
```

It's the only part where LIMIT for posts is added. And, as you can see, it is added only if `nopaging` is not set. So if `posts_per_page` is set to -1, then paging part of SQL query is not added.

So what can you do to work it around? You can set `numberofposts` to some big positive number.

Answer (score 0):

Set 'numberposts' value to a large positive number. With numberposts set to -1 it will return all the faqs ignoring the offset value.